# Matching dates with conditions and filtering in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

So I have a tables like this

```
id | date1   |date2   |value  
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2009|200  
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2009|200   
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2016|300  
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2009|200   
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2009|200    
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2016|300   
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2009|200  
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2009|200   
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2016|300
```

> NOTE: Value col values could be random

How do I get the rows with date1>=date2 over various ids.

> Essentially, if date1 is 2014 then I want to get just the row where
>   date1-date2 is minimum but not negative.

The result for the example table would look like this:

```
id | date1   |date2   |value  
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2009|200  
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2009|200  
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2016|300
```

I hope I explained it well, if not, feel free to ask.

I am using MS SQL SERVER 2014

so far I have tried:

```
select id,date1,min(date2) over (partition by id,date1 order by id, date1) date2, value   
from tblA
```

This gives me:

```
id | date1   |date2   |value  
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2004|200  
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2004|200   
1  | 1/1/2014|1/1/2004|300  
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2004|200   
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2004|200    
1  | 1/1/2015|1/1/2004|300   
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2004|100  
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2004|200  
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2004|200   
1  | 1/1/2017|1/1/2004|300
```

Here is a link to [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=21356c4bfc2476ee5bcb41e905fd315a) with the table

Comment: All of the rows in your attempt match your requirement of `date1 >= date2`.  Your requirement must be missing some information.

Comment: @MichaelKutz made an edit to update the requirement for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is rank the data based upon the smallest difference between the dates, per year - but you only need to consider any rows where `date1` is greater that `date2`. For this, I would personally use a CTE to filter and rank the results before returning it like so:

```
WITH results
AS(
  SELECT id, date1, date2, value
       , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id, date1 
                ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, date1, date2) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM tblA
   WHERE date1 >= date2
)
SELECT DISTINCT id, date1, date2, value
  FROM results
 WHERE rnk = 1;
```

You can find the results on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8a46922ceb2b1337e90b4e9c10fd5452).

For more information see the official documentation of [RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: this wouldnt work if the VALUE is random. It does not always follow that trend

Comment: You did not explain that in your question - I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for the fix! In your answer the date1>=date2. Other then that, works for me!

Comment: Thanks, I have adjusted my answer to include that.